# How to apply change from gradient descent to weights in my Neural Network?

Tags: python, neural-network

I have a neural network class in python that uses backpropogation to return the change of weights in relationship to the change in my cost function. I then run it through this function

```
def GradientDescent(self,DcOverDwL_jk,stepSize):
    self.NegGrad = -1*(DcOverDwL_jk)
    self.change = stepSize*self.NegGrad
```

This may sound a stupid question but what do I now do with the "change" value? Do I add this to every weight in the network?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, you add it to your weights.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the gradients for theta, you have to multiply it by the learning rate (alpha) and if you haven't already, divide it also by the number of training examples. Then you subtract it from the original theta. You do this for every weight and do this is for each ***training set iteration*** (steps). And if you chose your learning weight and architecture well, your final hypothesis should give you the local minima of the cost function (unless convex).

```
for i in range(steps):
    #do forward prop
    #do back prop
    theta1 = theta1 - ((1/m) * (alpha * grad1))
    theta2 = theta2 - ((1/m) * (alpha * grad2))
```